# Display data in Vue.js with v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm making a simple shopping cart system using Laravel and Vue.js. I can successfully add items to my shopping basket and retrieve them to a certain point, but I'm having trouble actually outputting the items to the view.

When I hit my basket route, I load the basket view which triggers the following Vue code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#basket',
  ready: function () {
    this.fetchBasket();
  },
  methods: {
    fetchBasket: function(){
      this.$http.get('api/buy/fetchBasket', function (basketItems) {
        this.$set('basketItems', basketItems);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

This works and I get data returned in the console:

```
{027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da: 
{id: 1, name: "A Gnarly Tree", price: 15, quantity: 2}}
  027c91341fd5cf4d2579b49c4b6a90da:
  {id: 1, name: "A Gnarly Tree", price: 15, quantity: 2}
    id:1
    name:"A Gnarly Tree"
    price:15
    quantity:2
```

However, nothing appears in the view itself. I'm trying to use `v-for` to populate a table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="item in basketItems">
        <td>@{{ item.name }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.price }}</td>
        <td>@{{ item.quantity }}</td>
        <td>@<button class="btn btn-primary">Update</button></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does the @ before the mustaches do?

Comment: @gurghet tells Blade (laravel templating engine) to ignore it, otherwise it will treat it as a PHP echo, basically.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the basketItems in the data of your vue instance. Try to add:

```
...
el: '#basket',
data: { basketItems: [] }, // <-- this line
ready: function(){
  this.fetchBasket();
},
...
```

Also edit

`this.$set('basketItems', basketItems);`

to

`Vue.set(this, 'basketItems', basketItems)`

Comment: No luck I'm afraid

Comment: Don't use `this.$set` is deprecated, I edited my answer

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/gurghet/dL2m248z/1/ what does the `basketItems` variable contain? are you sure you don't need to display `basketItems.data` instead?

Comment: It must be some problem with the way the data is returned from the controller. As you can see from the question, the actual data is contained in a collection or something with a weird random string.

Comment: Well, you can't expect Vue to magically guess a random string. You should access it with something like: `Object.keys(basketItems.something)[0]`. You should update your question with the content of that `basketItems` variable